# Rsnapshot log entries: "Number of hard links > 1"

Tags: cron, rsnapshot

I just noticed that my syslog is being spammed by rsnapshot, writing `<host name> cron[1100]: (*system*rsnapshot) NUMBER OF HARD LINKS > 1 (/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot)` every minute or two.

It seems they stop coming if I comment out all jobs from my rsnapshot cron file but that's not a viable solution in the long run.

Where does it come from, and what can I do about it?

(Running Ubuntu 18.04 server and rsnapshot 1.4.2)